# Scala import TSV

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm having some issues in parsing a TSV file in Scala. Following is the code that performs operations on the code.

```
var lines = file.map(_.split('\n'))
var nodes = lines.foreach( _.split('\t').map(_(1),_(2)).groupBy(_(1)).reduceByKey(_ + _))
```

Input

```
1 a 24
2 a 3
3 b 6
```

Desired Operation

```
a 27
b 6
```

I'm getting an error on performing split('\t') citing it not being a member of Array[String] which is quite strange as _ inside the foreach should refer to each element taken one at a time. Appreciate your assistance

Comment: What is `file`'s type?

Comment: file should be a string as it is read through ```file = sc.texFile(path)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the assignment of a foreach is Unit, so that's not what you want.  Use immutable vals. It's also not clear what format file is, so somehow you have to get a string there.

```
val file = "1\ta\t24\n2\ta\t3\n3\tb\t6" 

val lines = file.split("\n")
val nodes = lines.map(_.split("\t")).map(a => (a(1),a(2))).groupBy(_._1).map(a  => (a._1,a._2.map(b => b._2.toInt).sum))
//Map(b -> 6, a -> 27)
```

That's a big hot mess so I'll try to break it down:

```
val lines = file.split("\n")          //split string into array of lines
val nodes = lines.map(_.split("\t"))  //split each line into array of strings
  .map(a => (a(1),a(2)))              //get just the second two items from the array as a tuple
  .groupBy(_._1)                      //group by the first item in the tuple
  .map(a  => (a._1,a._2.map(b => b._2.toInt).sum))  //take each tuple and map the second value (an array of strings) into an array of ints and get the sum
```

If you don't like the map for the final output you can easily change it with `toList` or map the Map to anything you want.

Comment: The original error still persists: ```value split is not a member of Array[String]``` on the line of ```lines.map(_.split('\t')```

Comment: Glad you got it solved. For the original solution it would seem that the type of file is not what you think it is.  When I use file as a string in my response the value of lines is List[String].  What were you getting?